# Getting access token with UserAssertion gives error: Error validating credentials

Tags: c#, oauth, office365, azure-active-directory, office-addins

I'm currently in the process of developing an app for Outlook. I have a Javascript add-in project and an MVC Web API project. I'm trying to sent the token from the add-in down to the API, and from said token, get a new token to access Sharepoint and Exchange.

Currently I'm getting the following error:

> AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50013: Assertion audience claim does not match the required value.

Here is how I get the token from the Javascript add-in:

```
//GET NEW ACCESS TOKEN
var _mailBox = Office.context.mailbox;
_mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync(function (result) {
    var token = result.value;

    var item = _mailbox.item;

    //The initial ajax to the Web API
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "https://192.168.0.150:30303/api/api/uploadfile";
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'MailId': item.itemId,
            'SpListguid': guid //GUID of the Sharepoint list we wish to upload this email to
        }),
        headers: {
             'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).done(function () {
        console.log("Successfully hit the service");
    }).error(function (err) {
        console.log("Something went wrong! Oh boi!");
        console.log(err);
    })
})
```

And here's how I handle the token in my MVC Web API:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers"Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept", methods: "GET, POST, OPTIONS")]
public class APIController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionTResult UploadFile(){
        using(ClientContext clientcontext = SharePointHelper.GeClientContextWithAccessToken(this.ControllerContext))
        {
            //Do something once done 
        }
    }   
}
```

Here's the class `SharePointHelper` with the method `GetClientContextWithAccessToken(HttpControllerContext)`:

```
public class SharepointHelper
{

    public static Clientcontext GetclientcontextwithAccessToken(HttpControllercontext controlerContext)
    {
        string tenantId = {my-tenant-id};
        string authority = string.format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", tenantId);
        string resource = {the-app-id-uri-from-my-addin-in-azure}; //example could be "https://sharepointcommunity.com/outlookaddin"
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority)

        var authResult = AcquireUserAssertionAccessToken(controllerContext, authContext, resource)
    }

    private static AuthenticationResult AcquireUserAssertionAccessToken(HttpControllercontext controllercontext, AuthenticationCotnext authContext, string resource)
    {
        var rawToken = controllerContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization").First();
        string userAccessToken = token.Substring(token.LastIndexOf(' ')).Trim(); //To remove the "Bearer"
        var cc = new ClientCredentials({my-client-id}, {my-client-secret});
        var ua = new UserAssertion(userAccessToken);
        var result = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, cc, ua);
    }
}
```

The last line is where the error occurs (the `var result = ...`).

I'm not sure if this happens because of a faulty identity token from the JavaScript add-in, or if something else is wrong.

**Note:** the JavaScript add-in in AAD has permissions to the MVC Web API in AAD. And the MCV Web API has permissions to Exchange and SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

With the premise that I don't know what the office guys do in their wrapper methods exactly.

1. The resource you should request on the server side is not your
   addin, but sharepoint or exchange. Having the API request a token
   for the frontend does not serve any purpose that I can think of. If
   you fix that and it still doesn't work.
2. Try building the `UserAssertion` with

```csharp
string userName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn) != null ? ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value : ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(userAccessToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userName);
```

Comment: I managed to get it working. Instead of using identity tokens, I just used the `acquireToken(resource function(){})` where `resource` equals the APP ID URI of my API service in AAD. This solved the problem, but I appreciate your input